# Using both ref and active_id at once in record field

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13

In `xml` I want to use both `active_id` and `ref` as `context` field's value at once while defining `record` for model `ir.actions.act_window`. But I am able to use only one as shown in below code snippets:

Method 1. Using only `ref` with `eval`:

```xml
<record id="some_identifier" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Name</field>
    ...
     <field name="context" eval="{'some_key': ref('module_name.ext_id')}" />
</record>
```

Method 2. Using only `active_id`:

```xml
<record id="some_identifier" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Name</field>
    ...
     <field name="context">{'search_default_employee_id': active_id}</field>
</record>
```

When I try using `active_id` in *Method 1.* or include `ref` in *Method 2.* above I get an error message saying **`active_id` is not defined** in first case and **`ref` is not defined** in second case.

What I would like to achieve is to be able to use both `ref` method and `active_id` variable at once. Something like below:

```xml
<record id="some_identifier" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Name</field>
    ...
     <field name="context" eval="{'some_key': ref('module_name.ext_id'), 'search_default_employee_id': active_id}" /> <!-- NOTE: Raises an exception -->
</record>
```

```xml
<record id="some_identifier" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Name</field>
    ...
     <field name="context">{'some_key': ref('module_name.ext_id'), 'search_default_employee_id': active_id}</field> <!-- NOTE: Raises an exception -->
</record>
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from v12 Odoo supports calling model method for evaluating field value. We can utilize this technique to use both `ref` method and `active_id` variable at once in `context` field's value in following way.

Define a method as follow in any `model` you want.

```py
from odoo import models, api
from odoo.tools.misc import unquote

class SomeClass(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'some_module.model.name'

    @api.model
    def _using_both_ref_and_active_id(self):
        ref = self.env.ref
        active_id = unquote("active_id")

        return {
            'using_ref': ref('external.identifier').id,
            'search_default_whatever_filter_name': [active_id],
            'default_whatever_field_name': active_id
        }
```

And then in `xml` access this `method` as follows:

```xml
<record id="action_view_some_id" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Files</field>
    ...
    <field name="context" model="some_module.model.name" eval="obj()._using_both_ref_and_active_id()" />
</record>
```